# Append Field Value to Each Log Message processed by Filebeat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I have a use case where I would like to append a field to each log message that is processed by filebeat. The value would be based upon the type of log read by filebeat.

For instance, lets say I have 3 log types: typeA, typeB, typeC. When filebeat recognizes an update to log type A, it appends a typeA value to each message before output the message.

I have a basic filebeat.yml configured and running, but I cannot figure out how to append data to each message.

Grateful for any insight. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at "Common Options" under filebeat docs for file input. Their is an option to add fields to your messages: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-fields

Here is a sample snippet:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  path: /path_to_your_typeA
  fields:
    name_of_your_additional_field: typeA
```

You can also use "tags" instead of fields, if you do not want to indulge in key/val option.

Comment: thanks Furhan S. I was able to get both fields and tags to work with my filebeat.yml. Your answer addressed my problem. thanks!